# how to add role to userinfo endpoint in identity server

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I have been using the identity server quick start application, and I want to add role information to be returned when I call the userinfo endpoint.

```
  public Claim[] GetUserClaims(UserServiceProxy.Dto.User user)

    {
        return new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, user.Username), 
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, user.Firstname),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, user.Lastname),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, user.Username),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, user.Role ?? "normal"), //have added this
        };
    }
```

and this is called from my GetProfileDataAsync

```
if (context.RequestedClaimTypes.Any())
        {
            var user = UserClient.FindByUserName(context.Subject.GetSubjectId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                context.AddRequestedClaims(UserClient.GetUserClaims(user.Result.User));
            }
        }
```

When I call the /connect/userinfo endpoint, I get this (no role):

> {"name":"joe3","given_name":"Joe","family_name":"Three","sub":"joe3"}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never mind, I discovered the problem was that I needed to:

1. Add a new Identity resource for Role to the list returned by
   GetIdentityResources

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
   {
       return new List<IdentityResource>
       {
           new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
           new IdentityResources.Profile(),
           new IdentityResources.Email(),
           new IdentityResource{Name = "roles", UserClaims={JwtClaimTypes.Role}}
       };
   }
   ```
2. Add the role scope to the AllowedScopes list for the client

   ```
   AllowedScopes = new List<string>
               {
                   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                   "roles",

               },
   ```
3. In the request add a request for the roles scope.

   ```
         "RequestedScopes": "openid profile email roles",
   ```

Comment: Yes, the key thing is that in your `ConfigureServices` you are somehow adding `IdentityResources` in addition to just `ApiResources`. The `IdentityResources` that you've then defined will be what is provided on the `userInfo` endpoint